# Locking UIImageView while moving

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, quartz-graphics

I move a `UIImageView` with `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`. It works well, but  the touches get also applied to other `UIImageView`s, laying around.

How do I lock touching activity while moving the `UIImageView`? I've tried this with a boolean value, but it hasn't worked, because `touchesMoved` get called every time the `UIImageView` moves, not only one time.

Comment: Are you looking to stop touches on other views or only deal with one touch event per moving session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to make it so that only one imageView can be affected by user interaction at any time.  If that's the case, just set `imageView.exclusiveTouch = YES`.  Once a touch begins in any view with `exclusiveTouch` enabled, no other view in that window will register any touches.